# Nginx proxy redirect without changing url

Tags: nginx

I have a nginx (:80) and an upstream server (:8080) running on my machine.

- I want to proxy all requests to /assets/(*.?) to upstream's /upstream/$1 location.
- The upstream server redirects (302) /upstream/file_id to the /real/file/location.ext

Here is my code:

```
location /assets/ {
    rewrite ^/assets/(.*) /upstream/$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
}
```

This seems to work, but on the client side I get the redirected location:

```
http://myserver.com/real/file/location.ext
```

I kinda want to hide it so that it stays:

```
http://myserver.com/assets/file_id
```

The idea behind this is to make the upstream server find the real file's location, but let the nginx serve the file without giving away its real location. Is this even possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

first you're using 8000 in proxy_pass, but you're mentioning your port is 8080.

Second, remove the rewrite line should do the trick, because youre actually using the rewrite rule here and never get to the proxy_pass line. Something like the following should work:

```
location /assets/ {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

There are also proxy_rewrite and proxy_redirect commands which might help you in getting this upstream-redirect handled internally by nginx.

Hope that helps!